# Is there a Nginx environment variable equivalent to Apaches' {ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, seo, url-rewriting

When migrating from Apache to Nginx certain rules from the .htaccess file have to be 'translated' to Nginx the configuration file.
One problem I can't seem to solve, an example is the easiest way to explain:

The request `http://www.domain.com/nginx` is internally rewritten by Apache to `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=145`
Now I would like to block direct requests to `index.php?option=com_content` so the page is only available thru `http://www.domain.com/nginx` in order to avoid duplicate content. In Apache this was achieved by using these .htaccess rules:

```
# Check if it's the first pass to prevent a loop. In case of first pass, the environment variable contains nothing 
# If http://www.domain.com/nginx already internally has been rewritten to index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=145 {ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} contains '200' and the request is allowed to be processed
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# Check if the query string contains requests for the page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=145 [NC]
# If conditions apply, reject request
RewriteRule .* 404 [L]
```

In Nginx, is there such an environment variable that I may use?
Or should I approach this in a totally different way?

**EDIT 1:**
In real life, it is not only that one page but a dynamic Joomla site with lots of pages. I tested the above which works, but the intention is to block ALL requests on index.php?option_content&view=article&id=*

**EDIT 2:**
This is the working NGINX configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/domainname;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name domainname.com;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # deny running scripts inside writable directories
    location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
             return 403;
             error_page 403 /403_error.html;
    }

    ## give 404 header & redirect to custom errorpage without changing URL ##
    error_page   404  =  /404_custom.php; #global error page, script handles header
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location =/index.php {
        set $arg_set "${arg_option}___${arg_view}___${arg_id}";
        if ($arg_set ~* "^(((\w|-)+?)___){2}((\w|-)+?)$") {
            return 404;
        }
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is directive `internal` http://nginx.org/r/internal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache approach will not work here, but there are many other ways you can go about this problem, depending on how many such rules you are going to implement and some other conditions. In general case, I would use something like this:

```
map "${arg_option}___${arg_view}___${arg_id}" $show404 {
    default 0;

    # Put here the argument value sets of the pages 
    # you want to hide - one set per line
    "com_content___article___145" 1;
}

server {
    ...

    location /nginx {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=145 break;
        proxy_pass ...
    }

    location =/index.php {
        if ($show404) {
            return 404;
        }

        proxy_pass ...;
    }

    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to block all requests to index.php where the arguments "option", "view" and "id" are present, no matter what their values are, you could use something like this:

```
location =/index.php {
    set $arg_set "${arg_option}___${arg_view}___${arg_id}";

    if ($arg_set ~* "^(((\w|-)+?)___){2}((\w|-)+?)$") {
        return 404;
    }

    proxy_pass ...
}
```

In case some values of these arguments should be checked, just modify the regular expression to suit your purpuse:

```
location =/index.php {
    set $arg_set "${arg_option}___${arg_view}___${arg_id}";

    if ($arg_set ~* "^com_content___article___(\d+)$") {
        return 404;
    }

    proxy_pass ...
}
```

Also, in your situation map can be used to simplify the configuration, so that you wouldn't have to add another location for every article, instead encapsulating all the rewrite rules in one map block like this:

```
map "$request_uri" $real_args {
    default "";

    "~*^/nginx"            option=com_content&view=article&id=145;
    "~*^/some_article"     option=com_content&view=news&id=123;
    "~*^/another_article"  option=com_content&view=article&id=515;
}

server {
    ...

    location / {
        if ($real_args) {
            rewrite ^.*$ /index.php?$real_args break;
        }

        proxy_pass ...
    }

    location =/index.php {
        # See above
    }

    ...
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

For one or two exceptions you could improve your regular expression, using a [negative look-ahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
if ($arg_set ~* "^(((\w|-)+?)___){2}((?!175$)(\w|-)+?)$") {
    return 404;
}
```

But if you expect to have a lot of such URLs, you'll have to introduce map into your configuration after all. Otherwise your regular expression will get too complicated and unmanageable. The configuration in this case would look like this:

```
map "${arg_option}___${arg_view}___${arg_id}" $exception {
    default 0;

    "com_content___article___175" 1;
    "com_content___news___188" 1;
    "something___else___211" 1;
}

server {
    ...

    location =/index.php {
        set $arg_set "${arg_option}___${arg_view}___${arg_id}";

        if ($exception) {
            break;
        }

        if ($arg_set ~* "^(((\w|-)+?)___){2}((\w|-)+?)$") {
            return 404;
        }

        proxy_pass ...;
    }
    ...
}
```

This might seem somewhat counterintuitive but that's just how "if" works in Nginx. The second "if" will not be evaluated if Nginx meets break in the first "if" block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The example I gave was a simplification of the thruth for clarity reasons. In real life, it is not only that one page but a dynamic site with lots of pages. I tested the above which works, but the intention is to block ALL requests on index.php?option_content&view=article&id=*
Could that be done with map?

Comment: @cavuyk In this case you don't need to use map at all. Just check your request arguments against an appropriate regular expression and return 404 if it matches. I have updated the original answer.

Comment: This configuration works (posted above in question), your answer accepted, thanks. However, I do not yet understand why the direct request on index.php is blocked, while the CMS still is able to use index.php. Is it possible to describe the internal processing so I'll be able to understand it?

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk When answering your question, I was sure that you wanted to redirect requests manually in Nginx. I see now that you've got a CMS that takes care of the routing, exactly as it should be.

Your current configuration works, because Nginx only deals with HTTP requests from clients and Joomla does not make another HTTP request, when routing a SEF URL. The whole process never leaves Joomla — neither the client nor Nginx know that the actual handler of the request is index.php.

Comment: So, as I understand, when the request is "www.domain.com/nginx", the first location block "location /" catches the request. 
But when the request is "www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=145" location block "location =/index.php" catches the request and returns 404 to Nginx which is executed by the error_page directive. But, what would you do when you would still wanted to keep say "www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=175" for direct requests?

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk Yes, you got it right. I updated the original answer to provide some examples on how you can get around this rule for some specific URLs.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! The only thing now that is not good, is that when the request is "/index" without querystring, it should not give www.domain.com but the errorpage. I tried to add this to locations but without success. I can imagine that you had enough of this case, no hard feelings if you don't answer this, anyways thanks.

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk I didn't quite understand your last problem. If you want to show some error when a user is requesting /index.php without arguments, just check if $args is empty at the top of your index.php location like this: if ($args = "") { return 404; }. You can use any valid response code instead of 404 if you like. In case you want to spread this check to both /index.php and /index without php, just replace "location =/index.php {" with "location ^~ /index {".

Comment: That's right, index.php should not be accessible. But when I add  if ($args = "") { return 404; }, a 504 Gateway Time-out occurs. The accesslog: 
81.206.125.28 - - [21/Apr/2015:14:37:01 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 504 191 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
178.62.141.76 - - [21/Apr/2015:14:37:01 +0200] "GET /nl/error HTTP/1.1" 504 191 "-" "-"
178.62.141.76 - - [21/Apr/2015:14:37:01 +0200] "GET /nl/error HTTP/1.1" 504 191 "-" "-" etc. etc.

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk Are you sure that this problem was related to the changes you had made in your Nginx configuration? Judging by the look of it, every request at that moment of time met 504, not only the request to index.php. And this error only occurs when Nginx cannot receive the response from a backend for some time, which usually indicates a backend problem. Is it possible that at that moment there was some kind of trouble with Apache (or whatever you use as a backend) or your database? Did you try to open your error page directly? Maybe there is/was an infinite loop or something like that?

Comment: Yes, it seems like a loop. In the log the first request is from outside (IP 81.206.125.28), then all others are from within the server (IP 178.62.141.76). 

I tested the other pages, and not only the errorpage but all pages give this error. I only use Nginx, there are no other problems with the database. 

When I remove the " if ($args = "") { return 404; }" the system is running again normally.

It does work normally when I use if "($args = "") { return 301 $scheme://$host/nl/?h=1 ; }" but I would like to return a 404.

Comment: This indeed was my fault. I didn't read the configuration you provided carefully. The thing is, almost all users' requests end up in the =/index.php location, because of both "index" and "try_files" directives. In that situation checking $args was a bad idea, because this is okay for it to be empty in case of internal redirects. You need to check $request_uri instead: if ($request_uri = "/index.php") { return 404; }". If there's still any problem after that, please, show full contents of the configuration file.